# ASPNET. Signed PDF file saved to sql server, problems when retrieving

Tags: asp.net, pdf, signed

I've spent several days trying to find solution to this problem also I've search the web the best that I can and I don't know what else to do, this is what happens:

I've signed a PDF (I don't know if this is relevant but I mention it anyway) and I've saved its bytes array into an SQL server datatable, inside a varbinary field.

When I retrieve the data and i use the net method `File.WriteAllBytes` to create a PDF in the server, it works and I get the signed PDF.

But, if I use any `Response` object's method to download that file or the array of bytes saved on the database (`TransmitFile`, `OutputStream.Write`, `BinaryWrite`), I get a blank PDF file, and its byte content doesn't match the original file content.

I've tried all those methods and changed many properties (`contentType`, `AddHeader`, ...) unsuccessfully.

The code that I've tried (as you can see there are a lot of different approaches):

```
arrByte = CType(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("DATA"), Byte())

'HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""test.pdf""") 
Dim oStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(arrByte)
LoadStreamToStream(oStream, Response.OutputStream)

'File.WriteAllBytes(pdfPath, arrByte)
'Dim oFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(pdfPath)
''If (oFile.Exists) Then
'HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders()
'HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
'HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent()
'HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""test.pdf""")
'HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName
'Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
''HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", oFile.Length.ToString())
''HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", arrByte.Length.ToString())
'HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
''HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/download"
''HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
''HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(arrByte)
''HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(arrByte, 0, arrByte.Length)
''HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(oFile.FullName, 0, oFile.Length)
'HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(oFile.FullName)
'HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
''File.Delete(pdfPath)
'HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
''End If


Private Sub LoadStreamToStream(ByVal inputStream As Stream, ByVal outputStream As Stream)
    Const bufferSize As Integer = (64 * 1024)
    Dim buffer As Object = New Byte((bufferSize) - 1) {}

    While True
        Dim bytesRead As Object = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
        If (bytesRead > 0) Then
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
        End If
        If ((bytesRead = 0) _
                    OrElse (bytesRead < bufferSize)) Then
            Exit While
        End If

    End While
End Sub
```

I've uploaded three PDFs files to Mega, you can find them in this link:

https://mega.co.nz/#!ORAhQDxb!ewotEFGNeecGXwm1V1rGyGy0apFGPSiZee_tYztYrCY

*Password*: pdfs9587

**Right.pdf** is the one created with File.WriteAllBytes.

**Wrong1.pdf** is the one created when I try to download it and I've added a header with the file length.

**Wrong2.pdf** is the result of a response without putting the length in a header.

I thought maybe the length header was the problem but after several attemps I've seen that both errors repeat no matter what method for downloading the file I use.

However, comparing the three files, I think that the wrong one with the length header gets closer to the rigth one.

I hope you can give me some kind of advice or solution.

Thanks.

Comment: the PDF somewhere was considered text and written using UTF-8 encoding. That must not happen as it destroys the file. I would propose removing everything indicating some text encoding (especially the lines saying UTF8).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Before I added the encoding lines I used just the methods to transmit or write the file, unsuccessfully.

This part of the code creates a valid pdf:
   'File.WriteAllBytes(pdfPath, arrByte)
   'Dim oFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(pdfPath)

But all about the Response object (no matter how many changes I make) leads to a corrupted pdf :(

Comment: Finally I've decided not to use response object and open a link to the virtual directory in the server where I store the file created with File.WriteAllBytes method. I haven't been able to make it work through response.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've decided not to use response object and open a link to the virtual directory in the server where I store the file created with File.WriteAllBytes method. I haven't been able to make it work through response.